Multiple Date Columns but need a single date slicer
I have table that looks a bit like this:

Closed Date
Open Date
Notification Date
Scheme Code

I have three visuals that look at Scheme Code vs (respective) Date:

No. Scheme Codes by Notification Date
No. Scheme Codes by Opened Date
No. Scheme Codes by Closed Date

I need to create a date slicer that filters all of them individually.
I have created a universal date table but when I try to create a relationship to the columns, the other two get deactivated.
Whilst using sync slicers, I noticed that it was filtering incorrectly as it was taking into consideration all the dates, (e.g. filtering the scheme codes that were open, closed and notified)
I would like all three visuals to filter individually(e.g Scheme Codes opened in 2020, Scheme Codes Closed in 2020, Scheme Codes Notified in 2020) under one date slicer.

you can try to use USERELATIONSHIP to active the inactive relationship
USERELATIONSHIP
